After installing the cilium network, the node is in NotReady for a long time. It can be updated to Ready after restarting
I created a container network through helm in the installed kubernetes cluster, but the node was always in NotReady after creation. I accidentally restarted the server and found that the node status changed to Ready. After many attempts, I found that this was the case every time.
My environment information：
root@knode1:~# uname -a 
Linux knode1 6.8.0-41-generic #41-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Aug  2 20:41:06 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
root@knode1:~# cat /etc/os-release 
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 24.04 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="24.04"
VERSION="24.04 LTS (Noble Numbat)"
VERSION_CODENAME=noble
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=noble
LOGO=ubuntu-logo
root@knode1:~# kubeadm version 
kubeadm version: &version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"28", GitVersion:"v1.28.13", GitCommit:"024ab2a13ff700705efd3ab63a0e27c38c462070", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2024-08-14T19:49:21Z", GoVersion:"go1.22.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
root@knode1:~# ctr -v
ctr github.com/containerd/containerd v1.7.13

I installed cilium with the command：
helm install cilium cilium/cilium --version 1.15.6 \
    --namespace kube-system \
    --set kubeProxyReplacement=true \
    --set k8sServiceHost=10.0.0.21 \
    --set k8sServicePort=6443 \
    --set routingMode=native \
    --set loadBalancer.acceleration=disabled \
    --set loadBalancer.mode=dsr \
    --set loadBalancer.algorithm=maglev \
    --set hubble.relay.enabled=true \
    --set hubble.ui.enabled=true \
    --set bpf.lbExternalClusterIP=true \
    --set prometheus.enabled=true \
    --set operator.prometheus.enabled=true \
    --set hubble.enabled=true \
    --set hubble.metrics.enableOpenMetrics=true \
    --set ipam.operator.clusterPoolIPv4PodCIDRList="192.168.0.0/16" \
    --set ipam.operator.clusterPoolIPv4MaskSize=24 \
    --set ingressController.enabled=true \
    --set ingressController.loadbalancerMode=dedicated \
    --set loadBalancer.l7.backend=envoy \
    --set enableIPv4Masquerade=true \
    --set ipam.mode=cluster-pool \
    --set ipv4NativeRoutingCIDR="10.0.0.0/24" \
    --set hubble.tls.auto.enabled=true \
    --set hubble.tls.auto.method=helm \
    --set hubble.tls.auto.certValidityDuration=10950

Even after all nodes are ready, hubble-relay still fails to start, outputting：
root@knode1:~# kubectl logs -f -n kube-system hubble-relay-67f8875dfb-z5zc9 
time="2024-08-28T13:19:07Z" level=info msg="Starting gRPC health server..." addr=":4222" subsys=hubble-relay
time="2024-08-28T13:19:07Z" level=info msg="Starting gRPC server..." options="{peerTarget:hubble-peer.kube-system.svc.cluster.local:443 dialTimeout:5000000000 retryTimeout:30000000000 listenAddress::4245 healthListenAddress::4222 metricsListenAddress: log:0xc0002e9030 serverTLSConfig:<nil> insecureServer:true clientTLSConfig:0xc000729890 clusterName:default insecureClient:false observerOptions:[0x1f0ac00 0x1f0ace0] grpcMetrics:<nil> grpcUnaryInterceptors:[] grpcStreamInterceptors:[]}" subsys=hubble-relay
time="2024-08-28T13:19:12Z" level=warning msg="Failed to create peer client for peers synchronization; will try again after the timeout has expired" error="context deadline exceeded" subsys=hubble-relay target="hubble-peer.kube-system.svc.cluster.local:443"
time="2024-08-28T13:19:47Z" level=warning msg="Failed to create peer client for peers synchronization; will try again after the timeout has expired" error="context deadline exceeded" subsys=hubble-relay target="hubble-peer.kube-system.svc.cluster.local:443"
time="2024-08-28T13:20:07Z" level=info msg="Stopping server..." subsys=hubble-relay
time="2024-08-28T13:20:07Z" level=info msg="Server stopped" subsys=hubble-relay

Can anyone help me?
I don't know how to solve it, but I hope that hubble-relay can run normally, and after installing cilium, the node can smoothly transition to Ready state
